# Is there an efficient way to calculate the following power series?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find coefficients of a power series $K_p$ given by the equation:
$$\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2-2z\cos(\theta)} = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty}K_pz^p$$
where $\theta$ is a constant. I have checked that $K_0=1, K_1=2\cos(\theta), K_2 = 2\cos(2\theta), K_3 = 2\cos(3\theta)$. And I know that the answer is $K_p = 2\cos(p\theta)$. But is there an efficient way to derive the answer for an arbitrary $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

I guess that $z\in\mathbb R$. Then, take the real part of
$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty (e^{i\theta }z)^p =\frac{1}{1-ze^{i\theta }}.$$

Comment: That's a nice way. For the problem it needs a little modification. One needs to find the real part of $\frac{2}{1-ze^{i\theta}}-1=2\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}(e^{i\theta}z)^p-1$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients are
$2\cos(p\theta)
$.

(Just doing again what has
been done many times before.)

Writing $t$ for
$\theta$,

$\dfrac{1-z^2}{1+z^2-2z\cos(t)} = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
1-z^2
&=(1+z^2-2z\cos(t))\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p\\
&=(1-cz+z^2)\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p
\qquad c = 2\cos(t)\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p-cz\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p+z^2\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p\\
&=\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}a_pz^p-\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}ca_{p-1}z^p+\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}a_{p-2}z^p\\
&=a_0+a_1z-ca_0z+\sum_{p=2}^{\infty}(a_p-ca_{p-1}+a_{p-2})z^p\\
\end{array}
$

so

$a_0 
= 1,\\
a_1-ca_0 = 0,\\
a_2-ca_1+a_0 = -1,\\
a_p-ca_{p-1}+a_{p-2}=0
\text{ for }p > 2.
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
a_1 
&= c,\\
&= 2\cos(t),\\
a_2
&=-1+ca_1-a_0\\
&=-2+c^2\\
&=-2+4\cos^2(t)\\
&=-2+2(\cos(2t)+1)\\
&=2\cos(2t)\\
a_p
&=2\cos(t)a_{p-1}-a_{p-2}
\qquad\text{for } p \ge 3\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if we can show that
$2\cos(pt)
=4\cos(t)\cos((p-1)t)-2\cos((p-2)t)
$
for $p \ge 3$
we are done.

Since
$\cos(a\pm b)
=\cos(a)\cos(b)\mp\sin(a)\sin(b)
$,
$2\cos(a)\cos(b)
=\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)
$
so
$2\cos(t)\cos((p-1)t)
=\cos(pt)+\cos((p-2)t)
$
and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

If we use the generating function of the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind (see Abramowitz-Stegun 22.9.10) $$1/(1-2xz+z^2)=\sum_{n\ge 0} U_n(x)z^n,$$ the result should follow from a recurrence involving the transition $U_n \leftrightarrow U_{n-2}$ for the Chebyshev polynomials.